# Want to make WPF popup control to be movable( draggable )

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, drag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag WPF Popup control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222029/drag-wpf-popup-control)

I created a WPF popup control in my WPF form. When I click, the popup opens. Now I want to make that popup movable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pls look this answer
[Drag WPF Popup control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222029/drag-wpf-popup-control)