# A draggable popup control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need a draggable popup control in wpf and was wondering if any of your guys could help me out..I did see the following post:

[Drag WPF Popup control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222029/drag-wpf-popup-control)

but that isnt how its supposed to work...? When i click and drag it always resets to a specific point and moreover the commenters said that this is not an efficient approach...?
Does anyone have any alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: like the linked question says, you should probably use a Thumb instead of a popup

Comment: Can using a thumb move the popup when the mouse is moved...? I dont think so..as far as i know...? do you have an example of how we could use thumb to do drag ? thanks! sorry i am a beginner in wpf...so if my questions seem silly..I apologize..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open a child Window with a custom border layout. Then add a MouseDown handler that enables the dragging:

```
<Window 
        WindowStyle="None"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        SizeToContent="Height"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
...
</Window>
```

In code behind:

```
    private void Window_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks matthias...good suggestion...if I cant get the popup thingy to drag then ill use your solution i guess.

Comment: How do i set the window position relative to a specific control and enable it to be dragged only within another windows bounds?

Comment: Positioning the window should be possible by setting Window.Left and Window.Top after determing the position with PointToScreen(...). I don't know how to clip it to another window.

Answer (score 17):

We can write a behavior to make any `Popup` draggable.  Here is some sample XAML of a popup associated with a textbox that opens and stays open when the text box is focused:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Width="200" Height="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}" IsOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=textBox1, Mode=OneWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MouseDragPopupBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TextBlock Background="White">
            <TextBlock.Text>Sample Popup content.</TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Here is the behavior that allows us to drag the `Popup`:

```
public class MouseDragPopupBehavior : Behavior<Popup>
{
    private bool mouseDown;
    private Point oldMousePosition;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            oldMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            AssociatedObject.Child.CaptureMouse();
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!mouseDown) return;
            var newMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            var offset = newMousePosition - oldMousePosition;
            oldMousePosition = newMousePosition;
            AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset += offset.X;
            AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset += offset.Y;
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseDown = false;
            AssociatedObject.Child.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        };
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with behaviors, install the Expression Blend 4 SDK and add this namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and add `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project.

Comment: It's a straight-forward exercise to make the feature use code-behind instead.  Just add the handlers and change AssociatedObject to popup1.

Comment: oh ok cool...So I just need to replace the behavior with associated mouseup mousedown events in code behind is it? (replacing AssociatedObject with popup1) Thanks!