# Getting Compile time error "AssociatedObject" not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I implemented Popup control in Wpf.
I want to make popup drag able and found some code written below.
But I am getting compile time error "AssociatedObject" not found, Behavior Not Found.
Here is my code:

```
class class MouseDragPopupBehavior : Behavior<Popup>
{
    private bool mouseDown;
    private Point oldMousePosition;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            oldMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            AssociatedObject.Child.CaptureMouse();
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!mouseDown) return;
            var newMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            var offset = newMousePosition - oldMousePosition;
            oldMousePosition = newMousePosition;
            AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset += offset.X;
            AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset += offset.Y;
        };
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) =>
        {
            mouseDown = false;
            AssociatedObject.Child.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is `AssociatedObject` supposed to be then? It's not defined here.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact source code? `class class` at the start seems odd.

Comment: Yes actually i got this code from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784240/a-draggable-popup-control-in-wpf

Comment: Read the answer (where you copied the code from) to the end. It tells you what you're missing. And `class class` should of course be `public class`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A draggable popup control in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784240/a-draggable-popup-control-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`

Put `using System.Windows.Interactivity;` at the top of your class. You also need to add this as a reference in your project.

Also, you'll need to fix your `class` declaration, currently it is:

`class class ...`

It should be

`public class ...`